# Python Regular Expression returning nothing to repeat?

Tags: python, regex

So, what I'm trying to do is to parse a text file line by line into a list.

I've successfully done that. Now, I need to pull all the links that end with `.html` out.

Therefore I thought I would parse each line and if it matched `*.html`. So I believe the best way to do this is regular expressions. Below is my code and the error in question is the error returned about nothing to repeated. I've bolded the line it refers to.

Code:

```
compiled = re.compile("*.html") //Error Here
[m.group(0) for l in content for m in [compiled.search(l)] if m]
```

Just for the record I am trying to extract links that look like:

```
Nws_NewsDetails.aspx@Site_Id=2&lang=1&NewsID=148513&CatID=19&Type=Home&GType=1.html
```

But they could truly be random, hence the *.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Regular Expression, `*` is a meta character and it has a special meaning. That is why it gives you the error. You can use the following RegEx,

```
re.compile(".*\.html")
```

Here, `.*` means that any character can occur any number of times(0 or more times) (that is what `*` actually means in Regular Expression) and then you wanted to match `.`, so we match it by `\.`, as dot also has a special meaning (it matches any character), we need to escape it with `\`.

Comment: Oh ok. All the tutorials I kept reading referred to it as the wildcard character. I missunderstood. Ok I made the edit, however what would be the best way to print these results?

Comment: @Kyle We refer to that as wildcard character, usually, in the shells. And your method to print looks fine. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Still nothing, although it did print 1 extra blank line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51147/discussion-between-kyle-and-thefourtheye)